# GlobalFilters not working in MVC in method Application_Start

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-authorization

I am using the following in my web.config to block all users.

```
<authorization><deny users="*"/></authorization>
```

I want to authorize specific users at runtime and for that I have written the following code in `Application_Start` in `Global.asax` but it is not working as the user is still unable to access the page and receives access denied error.

```
GlobalFilters.Filters.Add(new System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute() { Users = "mydomain\\myuser" });
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't mix web.config authorization with attribute authorization.  In fact, web.config authorization is highly discouraged with mvc.

Comment: Secondly, if you want to authorize users at runtime, you don't want to do it in a global filter like that.  That runs only at application startup (not when a user logs on).

Comment: Thirdly, have you enabled Windows authentication in your site?

Comment: Yes Windows authentication is enabled. I want users to be able to authorize from single point (if that is possible) i.e. from one function or method rather than defining then in every controller or with every action. I am not sure if this is possible.